# How can I see the value of @jndiPattern@?

Tags: seam, seam2

Seam's component.xml is, by default, configured for the jndiPattern `@jndiPattern@`. Random googling suggests that this is a place holder for a real value. How can I see the real value?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I got it. The value is in components.properties. The line is

```
 jndiPattern=\#{ejbName}/local
```

Now, I still don't know what #{ejbName} means, but I'll get there.